# How to wrap a C++ class/struct with attributes that are vectors for fluid use in python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cython

I'm wrapping a C++ API for use in Python, so I'd like the functionality of the Python wrapper classes to pretty closely mirror that of the C++ classes. In one case, I have two objects that are actually nested structs:

```
// myheader.hpp
#include <vector>
namespace mynames{
struct Data{
    struct Piece{
        double piece1;
        int piece2;
        std::vector<double> piece3;
    };
    std::vector<Piece> pieces;
};
}
```

I'd like to interact with this object fluidly in Python as if it were a typical Python class using numpy and extension types. So I began by declaring two extension types:

```
# mydeclarations.pxd
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "myheader.hpp" namespace "mynames":
    cdef cppclass Data:
        vector[Piece] pieces

cdef extern from "myheader.hpp" namespace "mynames::Data":
    cdef cppclass Piece:
        double piece1
        int piece2
        vector[double] piece3
```

Then wrapping in Python:

```
# mytypes.pyx
cimport mydeclarations as cpp
from cython cimport NULL
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
import numpy as np

cdef class Piece:
    cdef cpp.Piece *_cppPiece

    def __cinit__(self):
            self._cppPiece = new cpp.Piece()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self._cppPiece is not NULL:
            del self._cppPiece

    @property
    def piece1(self):
        return self._cppPiece.piece1
    @piece1.setter
    def piece1(self, double d):
        self._cppPiece.piece1 = d

    @property
    def piece2(self):
        return self._cppPiece.piece2
    @piece2.setter
    def piece2(self, int i):
        self._cppPiece.piece2 = i

    # Use cython's automatic type conversion: (cpp)vector <---> (py)list (COPIES)
    @property
    def piece3(self):
        return np.asarray(self._cppPiece.piece3, dtype=np.double)
    @piece3.setter
    def piece3(self, arr):
        self._cppPiece.piece3 = <vector[double]>np.asarray(arr, dtype=np.double)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
cdef class Data:
    cdef cpp.Data *_cppData

    def __cinit__(self):
        self._cppData = new cpp.Data()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self._cppData is not NULL:
            del self._cppData

    @property
    def pieces(self):
        # Create a list of Python objects that hold copies of the C++ data
        cdef Piece pyPiece
        cdef int i
        pyPieces = []
        for i in range(self._cppData.pieces.size()):
            pyPiece = Piece()
            pyPiece._cppPiece[0] = self._cppData.pieces.at(i)
            pyPieces.append(pyPiece)
        return np.asarray(pyPieces, dtype=Piece)
    @pieces.setter
    def pieces(self, arr):
        # Clear the existing vector and create a new one containing copies of the data in arr
        cdef Piece pyPiece
        self._cppData.pieces.clear()
        for pyPiece in arr:
            self._cppData.pieces.push_back(deref(pyPiece._cppPiece))
```

This is a simple implementation and as far as I can tell it works, but there are some issues:

1. Since we use copies, there's no in-place functionality that you might expect if, for example, Piece().piece3 was a python class attribute holding a numpy array. For example,

```
a = Piece()
a.piece3 = [1,2,3]
a.piece3[0] = 55 # No effect, need to do b = a.piece3; b[0]=55; a.piece3=b
```

2. There's a lot of iterating over data and copying. This is probably an issue when the size of Data.pieces is very large.

Can anyone suggest some better alternatives to address these issues? Although Data is more complicated that Pieces, I think they are related and ultimately boil down to wrapping C++ classes with vector attributes for use in Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid data copying then it probably involves creating a wrapper class.

```
cdef class DoubleVector:
    cdef vector[double] *vec
    cdef owner

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if owner is not None:
            del self.vec

    @staticmethod
    cdef create_from_existing_Piece(Piece obj):
        out = DoubleVector()
        out.owner = obj
        out.vec = obj._cppData.piece3
        return out

    # create len/__getindex__/__setindex__ functions
    # You could also have this class expose the buffer protocol
```

Here I've assumed that `DoubleVector` doesn't own its own data the majority of the time. Therefore it keeps a reference to the Python class that owns the C++ class that owns that data (thus ensuring that object lifetimes are preserved).
Some details (mainly creating a nice sequence interface) is left for you to fill in.

---

Exposing `vector[Piece]` is more difficult, largely because any changes to the vector (including resizing it) would invalidate any pointers into the vector. Therefore I'd give *serious thought* to having a different Python interface to C++ interface.

- Could you make `Data` immutable (so that you simply can't change it from Python and so can safely return pointers into it)?
- Could you avoid returning `Piece` from data and have functions like `get_ith_piece1`, `get_ith_piece2`, `get_ith_piece3` (i.e. remove a layer from your Python wrapping)?

Alternatively you could do something like

```
cdef class BasePiece:
   cdef cpp.Piece* get_piece(self):
       raise NotImplementedError
   # most of the implementation of your Piece class goes here

cdef class Piece(BasePiece):
   # wrapper that owns its own data.
   # largely as before but with
   cdef cpp.Piece* get_piece(self):
       return self._cppPiece

   # ...

cdef class UnownedPiece(BasePiece):
   cdef Data d
   cdef int index
   cdef cpp.Piece* get_piece(self):
       return self.d._cppClass.pieces[index]
```

This is at least safe if the contents of the vector changes (it doesn't point to an existing `Piece`, but just to the indexed position). You obviously need to be careful about changing the size.

Your getter function for `Data.pieces` might be something like

```
@property
def pieces(self):
    l = []
    for i in range(self.pieces.size()):
        l.append(UnownedPiece(self.pieces[i], self))
    return tuple(l)  # convert to tuple so it's immutable and people
        # won't be tempted to try to append to it.
```

There's obviously a number of other approaches that you could take, but you can create a reasonably nice interface with this kind of approach.

The main thing is: restrict the Python interface as much as is possible.